# BeautifulSoup not scraping all HREF links

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

Two part question -- First, when running the code without final if statement, I'm not getting all of the HREF tags... I see many more links in Inspector that don't seem to come through.

Looking for a fix, but also trying to understand general knowledge on this - is there a reason why some links would work and others would not?

Similarly, I wanted to pull the HREF tags that contain "Surf-Report".  I've used this code with p.startswith, and it works... but I couldn't find what the function call would be to say "contains".

I'm new to all of this, looking but don't fully understand either of these.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

profiles = []
urls = [
    'https://magicseaweed.com/New-Jersey-Monmouth-County-Surfing/277/',
    'https://magicseaweed.com/New-Jersey-Ocean-County-Surfing/278/'
]
for url in urls:
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    for profile in soup.find_all('a'):

        profile = profile.get('href')

        profiles.append(profile)

# print(profiles)

for p in profiles:
    if p.contains('Surf-Report'):
        print(p)
```

For context, my overall goal is to go to these different county pages, and get all of the HREF tags there.  Once I have those, I want to visit each individual link and pull the wave sizes from each of the links stored there.

I'm looking to build a way to monitor all waves in New Jersey daily... no purpose, just a fun practice project with something I find interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those urls in page appears to be fed into dynamically, via an  (or more?) XHR call. Upon a brief inspection of that page' Dev tools - network tab, I noticed a call to an api (from which I stripped the variables). Scraping that api returns over 8k results:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

r = requests.get('https://magicseaweed.com/api/mdkey/spot?&limit=-1')
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
print(df)
```

Result:

|  | _id | _obj | _path | name | description | lat | lon | dataLat | dataLon | surfAreaId | dataSpotId | url | multiplier | optimumSwellAngle | optimumWindAngle | timezone | offset | modelName | isBigWave | ratingType | timeZoneAbbr | hasAdvancedForecast | proteusDataId | proteusResolution | surflineSpotId | defaultModelId | topLevelNav | tidalPort | isDataSpot | favouriteCount | mapImageUrl | breakingWaveModelId | weatherModel | added | hidden | edited | pointOfInterestId | useSDS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Spot | Spot | Newquay - Fistral North |  | 50.4184 | -5.0997 | 50.42 | -5.08 | 7 | nan | /Newquay-Fistral-North-Surf-Report/1/ | 0.7 | 290 | 110 | Europe/London | 3600 | glo_30m | False | directional | BST | True | nan | UK_4m | 584204214e65fad6a7709cec | 42 | True |  | True | 0 | https://chart-1.msw.ms/maps/spot/2576f3cfb35dba07a84590141d54d3a5.png | nan | gfs.0p25 | -62169984000 | False | 1617982527 | c10396fc-ed41-4771-8e8e-ab8dbff5c67c | True |
| 1 | 2 | Spot | Spot | Porthtowan |  | 50.2891 | -5.2461 | 50.27 | -5.3 | 6 | nan | /Porthtowan-Surf-Report/2/ | 0.8 | 290 | 110 | Europe/London | 3600 | glo_30m | False | directional | BST | True | nan | GLOB_30m | 5842041f4e65fad6a7708c98 | 38 | True |  | True | 0 | https://chart-3.msw.ms/maps/spot/d278b42dc4a8adc983a24e2c04333665.png | nan | gfs.0p25 | -62169984000 | False | 1617982527 | 39bca112-f093-4a7b-90eb-b7993920e5c4 | True |
| 2 | 3 | Spot | Spot | Gwithian |  | 50.2235 | -5.399 | 50.2 | -5.5 | 6 | nan | /Gwithian-Surf-Report/3/ | 0.5 | 285 | 105 | Europe/London | 3600 | glo_30m | False | directional | BST | True | nan | GLOB_30m | 5842041f4e65fad6a7708c95 | 38 | True | Perranporth | True | 0 | https://chart-5.msw.ms/maps/spot/2a4608d0e793ee20f4566ca85f5ba6cd.png | nan | gfs.0p25 | -62169984000 | False | 1617982527 | 6b0785be-1efb-413d-a5a9-ba2133c6ef68 | True |
| 3 | 4 | Spot | Spot | Sennen |  | 50.0802 | -5.6976 | 50.07 | -5.7 | 6 | nan | /Sennen-Surf-Report/4/ | 0.8 | 270 | 90 | Europe/London | 3600 | glo_30m | False | directional | BST | True | nan | GLOB_30m | 5842041f4e65fad6a7708c97 | 38 | True |  | True | 0 | https://chart-4.msw.ms/maps/spot/c1be3fe6871d15e4ea5297193b8b81da.png | nan | gfs.0p25 | -62169984000 | False | 1617982527 | a641e633-8692-4d4b-b2d6-c4e1d4132c9b | True |
| 4 | 5 | Spot | Spot | Constantine |  | 50.5333 | -5.0221 | 50.5759 | -4.92239 | 8 | nan | /Constantine-Surf-Report/5/ | 1 | 270 | 90 | Europe/London | 3600 | glo_30m | False | directional | BST | True | nan | GLOB_30m | 584204204e65fad6a77090b3 | 38 | True |  | True | 0 | https://chart-3.msw.ms/maps/spot/47b00f609d5e46cda66040d8b811bae6.png | nan | gfs.0p25 | -62169984000 | False | 1617982527 | 1daacdd5-a92a-4f7c-bc7c-af30a392ef7d | True |
| 5 | 6 | Spot | Spot | Bude - Crooklets |  | 50.8358 | -4.5548 | 50.8336 | -4.56057 | 8 | nan | /Bude-Crooklets-Surf-Report/6/ | 1 | 270 | 90 | Europe/London | 3600 | glo_30m | False | directional | BST | True | nan | GLOB_30m | 5842041f4e65fad6a7708ca5 | 38 | True |  | True | 0 | https://chart-1.msw.ms/maps/spot/553d3a850372eee8b10d13d23cbdb78e.png | nan | gfs.0p25 | -62169984000 | False | 1617982527 | 6cb522d3-a781-45ae-83cd-fcc941fd47cb | True |
| 6 | 7 | Spot | Spot | Croyde Beach |  | 51.1302 | -4.2435 | 51.1449 | -4.25995 | 9 | nan | /Croyde-Beach-Surf-Report/7/ | 0.8 | 270 | 90 | Europe/London | 3600 | glo_30m | False | directional | BST | True | nan | GLOB_30m | 5842041f4e65fad6a7708ca4 | 38 | True | Ilfracombe, England | True | 0 | https://chart-3.msw.ms/maps/spot/0f967e1e6130e9cb1b2623aafe966b58.png | nan | gfs.0p25 | -62169984000 | False | 1617982527 | 2dca4454-5789-4be3-808e-f512fef45dc3 | True |
| 7 | 8 | Spot | Spot | Praa Sands |  | 50.103 | -5.391 | 50 | -3.87 | 5 | nan | /Praa-Sands-Surf-Report/8/ | 0.8 | 210 | 30 | Europe/London | 3600 | glo_30m | False | directional | BST | True | nan | GLOB_30m | 5842041f4e65fad6a7708c9a | 38 | True |  | True | 0 | https://chart-4.msw.ms/maps/spot/aea8da3ce8bd22228c07c79db8e9b8de.png | nan | gfs.0p25 | -62169984000 | False | 1617982527 | a166dde9-2d1c-4a55-bb34-5a6efce93986 | True |
| 8 | 9 | Spot | Spot | Whitsand Bay |  | 50.3387 | -4.2434 | 50.3334 | -4.2433 | 5 | nan | /Whitsand-Bay-Surf-Report/9/ | 0.7 | 225 | 45 | Europe/London | 3600 | glo_30m | False | directional | BST | True | nan | UK_4m | 584204204e65fad6a77090c5 | 42 | True |  | True | 0 | https://chart-3.msw.ms/maps/spot/1fe1f342742ba3cf7dd3f8d9943948cc.png | nan | gfs.0p25 | -62169984000 | False | 1617982527 | c6b42c46-7db3-4e53-8f38-b28db957b4e7 | True |
| 9 | 10 | Spot | Spot | Bantham |  | 50.2787 | -3.8885 | 50 | -3.87 | 5 | nan | /Bantham-Surf-Report/10/ | 0.8 | 230 | 65 | Europe/London | 3600 | glo_30m | False | directional | BST | True | 2 | UK_4m | 584204204e65fad6a77090c9 | 42 | True | River Yealm | True | 0 | https://chart-1.msw.ms/maps/spot/358c02090c0c31888fee4794b39d397c.png | nan | gfs.0p25 | -62169984000 | False | 1646829186 | d3566d34-b58d-4803-8cf2-3e3dc5fc1a48 | True |

Is this what you're after?

Comment: This isn't exactly what I envisioned, but in some ways it's better. Phenomenal solution and explanation

Answer (score 1):

Since the website using `JavaScript` to load content you have to render the page before trying to search for `a` tags, so you should use `requests_html` instead of `requests`.
first you need to install `requests-html` library by typing `pip install requests-html`

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
profiles = []
session = HTMLSession()
urls = [
    'https://magicseaweed.com/New-Jersey-Monmouth-County-Surfing/277/',
    'https://magicseaweed.com/New-Jersey-Ocean-County-Surfing/278/'
]
for url in urls:
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=3, timeout=20) # wait for 3s until the page fully loaded
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.raw_html, "html.parser")
    for profile in soup.find_all('a'):
        profile = profile.get('href')
        profiles.append(profile)
for p in profiles:
    if p and 'Surf-Report' in p:
        print(p)
```

The result obtained :

```
/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/     
/Manasquan-Surf-Report/386/   
/Ocean-Grove-Surf-Report/7945/
/Asbury-Park-Surf-Report/857/ 
/Avon-Surf-Report/4050/       
/Bay-Head-Surf-Report/4951/   
/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/
/Boardwalk-Surf-Report/9183/
/Bradley-Beach-Surf-Report/7944/
/Casino-Surf-Report/9175/
/Deal-Surf-Report/822/
/Dog-Park-Surf-Report/9174/
/Jenkinsons-Surf-Report/4053/
/Long-Branch-Surf-Report/7946/
/Long-Branch-Surf-Report/7947/
/Manasquan-Surf-Report/386/
/Monmouth-Beach-Surf-Report/4055/
/Ocean-Grove-Surf-Report/7945/
/Point-Pleasant-Surf-Report/7942/
/Sea-Girt-Surf-Report/7943/
/Spring-Lake-Surf-Report/7941/
/The-Cove-Surf-Report/385/
/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/
/Avon-Surf-Report/4050/
/Deal-Surf-Report/822/
/34th-Street-Surf-Report/9058/
/Lavenia-Ave-Surf-Report/9060/
/Casino-Pier-Surf-Report/387/
/Harvey-Cedars-Surf-Report/7938/
/Hudson-Ave-Surf-Report/9062/
/Mantoloking-Surf-Report/9063/
/Ortley-Beach-Surf-Report/9064/
/Seaside-Park-Surf-Report/9280/
/Ship-Bottom-Surf-Report/9065/
/Spray-Beach-Surf-Report/9066/
/Surf-City-Surf-Report/388/
/34th-Street-Surf-Report/9058/
/Barnegat-Light-Surf-Report/7940/
/Beach-Haven-Surf-Report/7939/
/Casino-Pier-Surf-Report/387/
/Harvey-Cedars-Surf-Report/7938/
/Holyoke-Surf-Report/389/
/Hudson-Ave-Surf-Report/9062/
/Island-Beach-State-Park-Surf-Report/4052/
/Lavenia-Ave-Surf-Report/9060/
/Mantoloking-Surf-Report/9063/
/New-Jersey-Hurricane-Surf-Report/1094/
/Ortley-Beach-Surf-Report/9064/
/Seaside-Park-Surf-Report/9280/
/Ship-Bottom-Surf-Report/9065/
/Spray-Beach-Surf-Report/9066/
/Surf-City-Surf-Report/388/
/New-Jersey-Hurricane-Surf-Report/1094/
/New-Jersey-Hurricane-Surf-Report/1094/
/Casino-Pier-Surf-Report/387/
```

Comment: Note that the `render()` method will [download Chromium into your home directory.](https://github.com/psf/requests-html#javascript-support)

Comment: Yeah, this is gonna be automatic without doing anything

Comment: Amazing - works flawlessly; great lesson learned here, much appreciated

Comment: In a colab notebook this gives `Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.`